# Automatically create user accounts cent OS script "Is a directory" error

Tags: bash, centos7

I am working on a script to automatically create user accounts from a file in cent os 7. I keep getting an error saying that it is a directory. [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYYBW.png)

The script name is `generate`

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read first last; do
name="$first $last"
username="$last${first:0:1}"
n=‘egrep –c $username /etc/passwd‘
n=$((n + 1))
username=$username$n
useradd –c “$name” –m $username
password=`tr –cd ‘[:alpha:]’ </dev/urandom | head –c8`  
echo $password | passwd --stdin $username  
echo $username $password >> password_file.txt 
done
```

I am a beginner at this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So try to debug your script `bash -x ./generate` and see what really happens. Are you sure you use proper quotes? The `‘` are not `'` and `”` are not `"`. I don't think you need `egrep` here, just `grep` would be enough. And don't use backticks \`, they're use are discouraged and lead to errors like that, use `$(...)` instead.

Comment: Always turn off "smart quotes" when writing code.

Comment: Also try to avoid pictures, the errors can be posted as code format as well.

Comment: Thanks! i'm pretty sure i was just using the wrong quotes. It is working now.

Comment: You should use the `$()` syntax instead of quotes.  It avoids such issues.  One trick, put your code in https://www.shellcheck.net/, it will suggest good things to improve / fix.